# Dell latitude D820 vs D520

Tags: laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dell D520 vs D820 - need recommendation](https://superuser.com/questions/87737/dell-d520-vs-d820-need-recommendation)

hi

i ask before, but dont get any unequivocal answer

the same Memory 3G, same HD 250Gb

the D820 has screen 15.4 and intel Core 2 Duo 1.80Mhz T7100

the D520 has screen 15 and intel Core 2 Duo 2.00Mhz T7200

what's better ?

please help me to decide

Comment: Please don't post the same question more then once. Either update the original or unaccept the previouisly accepted answer. Also this question is highly subjective and not within the scope of SU, so I would suggest you rephrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most important difference is that the 520 is no longer available and the 820 is. Both are D series systems and you would be better off looking at the E ranges now in any cases as they are more up to date and better all round.

To anwser your specific question the 820 is a much more capable platform. To some extent you could configure an 820 and 520 to similar specs but even so the 820 was always a more robust and higher spec system. Some of the key differences between them were:

1. The 820 supports slightly better
   spec CPU's at the top end.
2. The 820 can have an
   nVidia Quadro video card, the 520
   can only be configured with the on
   board Intel GMA.
3. The 820 can be
   configured with a 1920x1200 res
   screenm the 520 maxes out at
   1400x1050.
4. The 820 can have an
   intgrated WWAN cellular adapter.
5. The 820 has a modular device bay can
   be used for both a secondary hard
   disk or an additional battery, those
   options are not available for the
   520.
6. The 820 has an Expresscard slot in
   addition to the PC Card slot, the
   520 only supports PC Card.
7. The 820 has an onboard Gigabit Ethernet
   capable adapter, the 520 only
   supports 10\100Meg Ethernet.

Any one of 2,3,5 & 7 would be enough to make me choose the 820 over the 520 if I had to make a selection. I certainly would not buy a business laptop that only had a 10/100 Ethernet adapter and having an option for an integrated second battery\hdd is extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there was no unequivocal answer to your previous question because it was too subjective.

You describe two very similar systems, but don't give any basis for assessing one as better than the other.

Maybe you should decide on price?

Comment: it dont cost me nothing, i need to get from my work

Answer (score 0):

The D520 may have a 4:3 aspect ratio screem.  You also do not mention what video card each has.  Are they the same video card?